# How to get the first 5 records f a query to use in another query

Tags: sql, presto

I have this query:

```
select name, score from tb
group by name, score
order by score desc
limit 5
```

and the output is:

```
name1   90
name2   85
name3   70
name4   50 
name5   30
```

Now I want to do the same query but using the names to perfom another query. I need to know how to "call" the 2ns highest score name, the 3th, 4th and 5th name in thesame order they appear in the first query.

something like this:

```
with 5_top as(  
select name, score from tb
    group by name, score
    order by score desc
    limit 5)
```

select `<2nd name_here>` from 5_top

So from the first query I know `name2`  is the 2nd highest score so in the next query I can just use where `name = name2` but if name2 next week drops to 3th position my query will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` window function to determine the the place. Note the explicit ordering for it:

```sql
WITH dataset (name, score) AS (
    VALUES ('name1', 90),
        ('name2', 85),
        ('name3', 70),
        ('name4', 50),
        ('name5', 30)
)
select * 
from (
        select *, row_number() over (order by score desc) rnk
        from dataset
    )
where rnk > 1
```

Output:

| name | score | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name2 | 85 | 2 |
| name3 | 70 | 3 |
| name4 | 50 | 4 |
| name5 | 30 | 5 |

Comment: If I have a tie in first position for example, what can I do?

Comment: @pouchewar it depends on what logic you need to implement. You can switch to `rank` instead of `row_number` which will give the same value for ties introducing gaps (i.e. 90, 90, 89 will result in 1, 1, 3)